# Making A quadradic factorer, While loop messes it up

Tags: python-3.x, list, for-loop, math, while-loop

> The program works perfectly fine, it's just if I decide to use the while loop it gives me nothing without an error but if I hashtag it out, everything works fine. The reason I want it to not be hashtagged out is that it would reciprocate the numbers in the list making it an issue down the road, Everything breaks even the factor list for some reason. I need help to figure out how to fix it.

````
    Factor_list = []
    Solved_Diamond_List =[]
    z = x2 * num
    No_Answer = True
    if z > 0:
        for i in range(-z, 0):
            if z % i == 0:
                    Factor_list.append(i)
        for i in range(1, z + 1):
            if z % i == 0:
                Factor_list.append(i)
    if z < 0:
        for i in range(z, 0):
            if z % i == 0:
                Factor_list.append(i)
        for i in range(1, -z + 1):
            if z % i == 0:
                Factor_list.append(i)
    for i in Factor_list:
        for j in Factor_list:
            while No_Answer == True:
                if (i + j) == x:
                    if (i * j) == z:
                        Solved_Diamond_List.append(i)
                        Solved_Diamond_List.append(j)
                        No_Answer = False```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your `while` loop does not terminate, unless the answer is generated in the particular combination of `i` and `j` you start with. Maybe rewrite to:

```
for i in Factor_list:
    for j in Factor_list:
        if No_Answer:
            if (i + j) == x and (i * j) == z:
                Solved_Diamond_List.append(i)
                Solved_Diamond_List.append(j)
                No_Answer = False
```

It's not optimal (it will run through all combinations of `i` and `j` even after finding the answer). Or maybe you wanted a list of all answers?

```
for i in Factor_list:
    for j in Factor_list:
         if (i + j) == x and (i * j) == z:
             Solved_Diamond_List.append((i, j))
```